# Listen to react-day-picker input 'change' event

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I am using the react-day-picker library to display a date picker on my site. I would like to listen for when the date has been changed. I know there are onDayChange hooks you can add to the `DayPickerInput` components, but I want to listen for a change outside of the component.

Example: (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-day-picker-base-mpcqy)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DayPickerInput from "react-day-picker/DayPickerInput";

import "react-day-picker/lib/style.css";

function Example() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>DayPickerInput</h3>
      <DayPickerInput placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" format="DD/MM/YYYY" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));

var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
input.addEventListener("change", () => {
  console.log("changed");
});
```

I would expect the on change handler to be fired. I'm not sure why it isn't. How can I listen to the value change?

Answer (score 4):

You can see answer of your question in `react-day-picker` [documentations](https://react-day-picker.js.org/docs/input)

You should pass event handler to your `DayPickerInput` component this way:

```
function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(undefined);
  handleDayChange(day) {
    setValue(day);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>DayPickerInput</h3>
      <DayPickerInput
       placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" 
       format="DD/MM/YYYY"
       onDayChange={day => handleDayChange(day)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the only method to listen to an event. Also you should know that it's very bad practice to mutate DOM directly.

And if you want to make `value` accessible globally, you should use React's [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/api/api-reference). (State management tool)